# IOS 11.1 SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile app using Cordova and jQuery Mobile.  My app was working fine for iOS 11.0.3 and then when iOS 11.1 came out, I am getting an error and unable to click on any links.  The error I get in the safari error console is "SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL."  I have added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: blob: ws: wss: gap://ready file://*; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * ws: wss:;">` because I thought it might be part of the Content Security Policy but I am still receiving the same error.  I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 and jQuery 2.1.1.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue on an Angular 1.7 application using Cordova.  Our application has stopped working once 11.1 was introduced.  We added the described meta tag prior to reading this post and it has not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please update following value in angular.js file.

**OLD VALUE:**

```
this.$$absUrl = appBaseNoFile + this.$$url.substr(1);
```

**NEW VALUE:**

```
this.$$absUrl = appBaseNoFile + this.$$url;
```

ios11 gives error because of this: `file:/// != file://`

Comment: I am not using AngularJS.  I am using jQuery Mobile for this.  Do you have any other suggestions that I could use?

Comment: Is there a better solution than modifying core angular to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i have exactly the same issue.

Disabling html5 mode worked for me (as im not using route or state providers)

Comment: How are you disabling html5 mode?

Comment: i think it wont work for you as it works only for angular.js;