# SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState()... in Angular 5

Tags: ios, swift

### Issue

I am receiving the following error:

> [Error] ERROR – Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked attempt to use history.replaceState() to change session history URL from file:///Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Bundle/Application//ios-shell.app/public/index.html to file:///Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Bundle/Application//ios-shell.app/public/#/. Paths and fragments must match for a sandboxed document.

The difference between the two urls is just the end `public/index.html` -> `public/#/`

There was a [similar question asked here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145052/ios-11-1-securityerror-dom-exception-18-blocked-attempt-to-use-history-replac) however this was an issue between `file:///` and `file://`

### Implementation

This is a custom iOS application created to run HTML SPA applications without cordova. Currently running in the Simulator on an iPhone 8 device on iOS 11.2 using the `WKWebView`

The web application is an Angular 5 application using `{hash: true}` as the routing strategy.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var serenity: Serenity?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        serenity = Serenity(self)
        serenity?.load("index")
    }

    ...
}
```

**Serenity.swift**

```
class Serenity: WKWebView, WKScriptMessageHandler{

    var controller: ViewController?
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    var commands = Dictionary<String, (_ args: Any?) -> Any?>()

    init(_ controller: ViewController){
        self.controller = controller
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: "window.NATIVE_DEVICE=true;", injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false))
        super.init(frame: controller.view.frame, configuration: config)
    }

    func load(_ file: String) {
        if let html = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "html", inDirectory: "public"){
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: html)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            super.load(request)
            controller?.view.addSubview(self)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**Question**

Is there a way to load the `index.html` file as `public/` so that when angular takes over and starts routing it doesn't cause this error?

Any other suggestions would be helpful as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

I modified my index.html file to have a base of `<base href="index.html">` instead of `<base href=".">` which forced angular to use routes like `.../index.html/#/` instead of `.../#/`.

#### Non-solution *(for future searchers)*

I attempted to load the directory and allow the `WKWebView` to load the index.html page by default by

```
if let html = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "html", inDirectory: "public"){
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: html)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url).deletingLastPathComponent()
    super.load(request)
    controller?.view.addSubview(self)
}
```

However this resulted in the `WKWebView` not loading the page at all.

Comment: I was getting the same error message in a plain desktop browser, unrelated to Angular or hash routes. However, the solution was nearly the same! I simply added `<base href="/" />` to `index.html` and bam, no more issues. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem for me in an Angular webapp inside a WKWebview. I also need to set useHash true on app routing module to let it work